# Wrong output for converting hex string from file

Tags: java

I am having problems with the output of my code. I have to convert a hex string from file to binary and then that binary to decimal. And then find the RAM error in the chip, which I have yet to code. My main concern right now is that when I run the program, my first result is correct, but for the rest 3 hex to binary output, the binary strings attach itself to the previous binary output and it becomes a long and wrong binary string.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("RAMerrors.txt"));

    String result = "";
    String binVal; // the binary value of the Hex

    while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = infile.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(line);
        String hex = input.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
            char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);

            switch (hexChar) {
                case ('0'):
                    binVal = "0000";
                    break;
                case ('1'):
                    binVal = "0001";
                    break;
                case ('2'):
                    binVal = "0010";
                    break;
                case ('3'):
                    binVal = "0011";
                    break;
                case ('4'):
                    binVal = "0100";
                    break;
                case ('5'):
                    binVal = "0101";
                    break;
                case ('6'):
                    binVal = "0110";
                    break;
                case ('7'):
                    binVal = "0111";
                    break;
                case ('8'):
                    binVal = "1000";
                    break;
                case ('9'):
                    binVal = "1001";
                    break;
                case ('A'):
                    binVal = "1010";
                    break;
                case ('B'):
                    binVal = "1011";
                    break;
                case ('C'):
                    binVal = "1100";
                    break;
                case ('D'):
                    binVal = "1101";
                    break;
                case ('E'):
                    binVal = "1110";
                    break;
                case ('F'):
                    binVal = "1111";
                    break;
                default:
                    binVal = "invalid input";
                    break;
            }
            result += binVal;
        }
        System.out.println("Binary of " + hex + ":" + result);
        System.out.println("And the decimal is " + convertBin2Dec(result) + "\n");
    }
}
```

And my Output looks like:

> Binary of ABCDEFABC: 101010111100110111101111101010111100
>   And the decimal is 46118402748
>
> Binary of 1A00D0000: 101010111100110111101111101010111100000110100000000011010000000000000000
>   And the decimal is 9223372036854775807
>
> Binary of 7A0EDF301: 101010111100110111101111101010111100000110100000000011010000000000000000011110100000111011011111001100000001
>   And the decimal is 9223372036854775807
>
> Binary of 3CDAEFFAD: 101010111100110111101111101010111100000110100000000011010000000000000000011110100000111011011111001100000001001111001101101011101111111110101101
>   And the decimal is 9223372036854775807

Comment: Add info to the question, not in comments. Unrelated, but it seems like simple sprintf formatting might be easier than a giant switch statement.

Comment: where can I write the printf statements to have the correct output?

Comment: Declare your variable "result" inside the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not clearing your `result` variable between checks.

If you declare `result` inside the while loop, it should fix your problem.

Comment: result is not cleared, binVal is assigned and that is ok.